# How to control the speed of jquery ui slider handle drag moment?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with the jquery ui slider, I created the multiple slider handles using the following code:
[Click to check the JS Bin code here](http://jsbin.com/olehir/18/edit)

Now the problem is, when I drag the slider handle slowly, the functionality works fine. When the slider drags fast all the functionality was collapse and some times the animate function will not work properly.

Any one having solution please let me know.
[Click to see js fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/satishchandra/jGKG7/1/)

Comment: Any particular browser? Works fine for me in Chrome [insert latest version number here] at whatever speed I move the handles

Comment: present i am checking in firefox 11.0

Comment: i mean that the labels(menu links) animation effect not working properly when i move the handles with certain speed.

Comment: I'm having same problem and still couldn't fix it.